# Invalid access token signature - Posting photo to fb page using app

Tags: facebook, oauth

I had an app running on facebook that would post photos to a facebook page but when I changed my facebook password my tokens reset. So i went back through the authentication process of getting all my tokens. and I keep getting this message. {"message":"Invalid access token signature.","type":"OAuthException"}}

I think the problem is that my page token is incorrect.  Compared to my old page token my new page token is an extra 30 something characters.  I'm thinking that I'm missing a step.

I'm getting my page's token by using https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=.

This is what my old page token looked like = ftXXXXXXXXXVJCeVnt-sKYoM

But now its like this: AAACeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXpLiXZCYCIEsBzK59vUcP00cpk4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXd2tnbCePVYLEuk0OBrQBmTRnGHfs3gZDZD

Am I missing a step with the page token?

I know its not a scope issue.  I've assigned every permission to this dang thing.

Thanks for the help.

here's a sample of my code that was working before i messed up all my token access.  I have my new token in here, that's what is giving me trouble.  Not the rest of the code. Any insight would be huge.

```
$access_token =  '1743XXXXXXXXX9104|fcdApQ4CXXXXXXXXXMo82SRHQh8o|81XXXXXXXXX70|AAACelwXXXXXXXXXuiTpY2BBwUZBpLiXZCYXXXXXXXXXcpk4g4FBkhpwykR0amEcdn1Kd2tXXXXXXXXXrQBmTRnGHfs3gZDZD';
$post_name = 'NAME';
$post_link = 'http://mykirklands.com';
$post_picture = '000000.jpg';
$post_description = 'description';

// CRAFT OUR MESSAGE TO POST
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id/photos";
$post_name = $content;
$post_picture = '@'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].''.$image;
$attachment[$count] = array('access_token' => $access_token,                        
'source'       => "$post_picture",
'message'      => "$post_name"
);
echo $count++;
}


foreach($attachment as $row){
// SEND TO FACEBOOK
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $row);
$result= @curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this.  It seems like facebook has changed a few things recently.

The old access token used to have a format of 
APP_ID|APP_TOKEN|PAGE_ID|PAGE_TOKEN

The new access token required to post to a facebook wall from an application is just:
PAGE TOKEN

The difference between the page tokens is in the length:
Old Token

```
4qVvc4wBz14_fgJLqE7PeQyLgaY
```

New Token

```
XXXXXXXXXXcnPXXXXXXXXXXVr3hmNPsqypxR9mXXXXXXXXXXXVGFdmQeWZCXXXXXXXXXXelrC69kdwZCXXXqD98IislBJ5YYYYYYYwZDZD
```

I'm guessing the new token contains enough security that it authenticates the app as well as the permissions given to the page.

I'm using a php script to post images posts to a page's facebook wall through cURL. Its also important to note that you need to include the token as a variable in the url you are sending to cURL.

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id/photos?access_token=$page_access_token";
```

I'm adding the important code block to tidy this thing up:

```
$attachment = array('message' => '',
'name' => "$post_name",
'caption' => '',
'link' => '',
'description' => "$post_name",
'source' => "$post_picture",
'actions' => array(array('name' => '', 
'link' => ''))
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
$result= @curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

All done.  Things are back to working order.  Please let me know if you have any questions about this.  I racked my head on a wall for 3 days before I got to this simple change. Hopefully no one else has to go through what I went through.